# How to point to the correct Store in Outlook automation by C#?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have a lot of VBA automation that interlinks an Outlook and Word solution; it is fine, but time is inexorable... so, I'm start to decorating and extending that old solution, wraping it with C#/VS2017.
Through a conventional Winform I can choose my patients, and from this action I do a lot of actions, including open the correct Outlook contact; that's the problem, because I can't get the correct Store; the patients.pst, depending on the machine, may be the 1st, 2nd, 3rd...
In VBA I do this:

```
    WhichStoreNameToPointAt="patients"
    Set myNamespace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    For i = 1 To myNamespace.Stores.Count Step 1
        If myNamespace.Stores.item(i).DisplayName = WhichStoreNameToPointAt Then
             intOutlookItemStore = i
        End if
    End If
    Set myFolderPatients = myNamespace.Stores.item(intOutlookItemStore).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
```

And it always functions like a charm.

In C# I tried a lot of variations, and could not point to the correct store:

```
    public void OpenPatientContact(string patientName)
    {
        Outlook.Store whichStore = null;
        Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = OlkApp.Session;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in nameSpace.Folders)
        {
            bool p = false;
            if (whichStoreNameToPointAt == folder.Name)
            {
                p = true;
                whichStore = folder.Store;
               //Correct Store selected; I can tell because of this watch:
               //whichStore.displayname == whichStoreNameToPointAt 
            } 
            i++;
            if (p)
                break;
        }
        var contactItemsOlk = whichStore.Session.GetDefaultFolder
                        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Items;
        // The problem is below; always the first Store
        Outlook.ContactItem contact = (Outlook.ContactItem)contactItemsOlk
                        .Find(string.Format("[FullName]='{0}'", patientName)); //[1];
        if (contact != null)
        {
            contact.Display(true);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The contact information was not found.");
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, it keeps pointing ever to the same first Store, the one that has no patients...
If I change the Store order I can get past this and test other stuff, but of course it is not the right way.

Any other heads/eyes to see the light?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While seated writing the question, looking at a yellow rubber duck - and a lot of other stuff that belongs to my 1 yo daughter ;), I realized that whichStore.Session.GetDefaultFolder is a little strange in this context. I only changed this

```
 var contactItemsOlk = whichStore.Session.GetDefaultFolder
                    (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Items;
```

To that:

```
 var contactItemsOlk = whichStore.GetDefaultFolder
                    (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Items;
```

Voilá! Magic happens with C# too!
Session [returns the default NameSpace object for the current session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application?view=outlook-pia).

PS: yellow rubber duck; guys of The Pragmatic Programmer really knows some secrets and tricks ;)

Thanks Thomas and Hunt!