# Export visual basic outlook project and add it to other outlook account

Tags: vba, outlook

I created two macros in Outlook's VB and I want to pass them on to others where I work. Is it possible to do this without copying the code to each account individually? Is there a way to export my project (or my modules) and import it into another account so that the macros I wrote will be added automatically?

Another option for me is whether it can be done in a small program written in C# (i.e. Console Application) with the Outlook namespace.

Comment: Right click your modules and export. Then add them in to your other workbooks `from existing files`.

Comment: for VBA Eugene Astafiev - The guy for VSTO - answered all. As for VSTO with C#, if you want to dig, do yourself a favor a get __Visual Studio Tools for Office 2007: VSTO for Excel, Word, and Outlook (Volume 1-2)__ original from Eric Lippert; This book is getting cheaper and it is a must. PS: do not buy the previous 2005 edition: Outlook object model changed a lot to remained useful.

Comment: Having saying that, even with the above recommend book, a lot of times I could only do things correctly in C# after seeing it to be correctly done by Sue Mosher in her magistral Microsoft Outlook 2007 Programming: Jumpstart for Power Users and Administrators.

Comment: And in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727015/how-to-point-to-the-correct-store-in-outlook-automation-by-c) I did the same thing in VBA and C#; may help you giving a Jumpstart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're developing a solution that you intend to distribute to more than a few people, you should convert your VBA code into an Outlook COM or VSTO add-in or an Office add-in for Outlook. However, developing an add-in typically requires considerably more programming knowledge than creating a short macro. If your VBA project is relatively simple, and there aren't too many people that have to use it, you may want to distribute the code together with instructions to set it up.

The easiest solution is to right click on `ThisOutlookSession` and choose `Export File`. You'll need to do for each module (if any) in your `Project`.

---

Unlike other Microsoft Office programs, Outlook supports only one VBA project at a time. VBA macros are stored in a file that's named `VbaProject.OTM`. This file is a product storage file and isn't meant for distribution. Outlook doesn't provide a direct means to manage OTM files. Outlook VBA code wasn't designed to be deployed or distributed. It was designed solely to be a personal macro development environment. The project, Project1, is available and associated with the program at all times. It's not possible to add another project in the Visual Basic Editor.

Project1 is stored on your hard disk as `VbaProject.otm` in the following folder:

```
<Drive>:\Users\<LogonName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook
```

If you want to begin a new VBA project, you could theoretically export all your existing modules and forms. But this is typically not a realistic approach. Instead, follow these steps:

1. Exit Outlook.
2. Locate your `VbaProject.otm` file in the indicated path.
3. Rename the file to something meaningful to you, such as `VbaProject-testing.otm`.
4. Restart Outlook.

Because Outlook can't find an existing project file, Visual Basic Editor starts with a new project. When you save changes to your project, Outlook creates a new `VbaProject.otm` file in the folder. If you want to switch between projects, add one more step to the previous procedure (as step 4):

1. Exit Outlook.
2. Locate your `VbaProject.otm` file.
3. Rename the file to something meaningful to you, such as `VbaProject-testing.otm`.
4. Restore the name the file that you now want to use as `VbaProject.otm`.
5. Restart Outlook.

If you want to move a VBA project from one computer to another, first determine where Outlook is storing the `VbaProject.otm` files on each computer. Then, copy the OTM file from one computer to the other, and make sure to put it into the correct folder. When you restart Outlook, the program will find the `VbaProject.otm` file and use it.

You may find the [How to backup and save your Outlook VBA macros](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-backup-and-save-your-outlook-vba-macros/) article helpful.

Comment: "Outlook COM or VSTO add-in or an Office add-in for Outlook" - can you point me to an article on how to do one of these?

Comment: See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019)